Mollification and limit
Consider the $d$-dimensional torus $\mathbb{T}^d.$ Let $\phi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R})$ such that $\phi(0)=1$ and $\phi_\epsilon(x):=\phi(\epsilon x),\rho\in C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^d).$
Prove: $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\left\Vert \mathscr{F}^{-1}\phi_\epsilon*\rho-\rho\right\Vert_{L^\infty(\mathbb{T}^d)}=0.$$
I know that the result is correct if we had a compact $K$ of $\mathbb{R}^d.$
How to deal with the $d$-dimensional torus case?
